# Azure AD - How to automate access for a Global administrator role to a User role in order to "Access files" from User role OneDrives?

Tags: powershell, azure, onedrive

I am working on proofing out if there is a way to automate a `Global administrator's` `Azure AD` access for other `User role` accounts in the same tenant to grant access to OneDrive.

If you navigate to [portal.office.com](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/users) and then click on a user's name, that will bring up some settings for that user. The setting I am referring to is under the dropdown for **OneDrive Settings**, (see attached image).

[image]

Is there a way to automate this process via some PowerShell cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I found an article that shows how to run `PowerShell` commands via the `SharePoint Online Management Shell`

Tutorial link has the section for *Prerequisites* for setup: [Easy Manage Multiple Office 365 Tenants with Windows PowerShell](https://www.itunity.com/article/easily-manage-multiple-office-365-tenants-windows-powershell-2770)

Actual `PowerShell` commands:

`$site = Get-SPOSite -Identity https://mydemo-my.sharepoint.com/personal/sarad_mydemo_onmicrosoft_com
Set-SPOUser -Site $site.Url -LoginName admin@mydemo.onmicrosoft.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true`

Tutorial: [How to Get Administrative Access to the OneDrive for Business Environment for a User](https://www.itunity.com/article/administrative-access-onedrive-business-environment-user-2792)